# How to Validate Receipts using phonegaps InAppPurchase Manager?

Tags: cordova, in-app-purchase

Does anyone have example code of how to validate receipts using PhoneGaps plugin, InAppPurchaseManager? I am looking to use the apple server, not my own to validate the receipts as well.